# Docker Webhook container: Should run a script, but the script doesn't get executed correctly (only echo's are working)

Tags: git, bash, docker, sh, webhooks

So I set up a Docker container, that is based on the one from [almir/webhook](https://hub.docker.com/r/almir/webhook/) and I added git and docker to the image, so I can run corresponding commands. The problem is, it runs when I test it manually and it even runs when I start the script from inside the container via a terminal. But when I trigger the script via a URL I only get the echo's as the output and no "real" commands get executed.

My script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "current directory: " + $PWD
git pull
echo "pulling from git"
docker exec -ti geda-drupal gedankenbruecke/vendor/drush/drush/drush st
echo "clear drupal cache"
echo "Script finished successful"
echo "testPull"
```

My output is this:

```
[webhook] 2017/10/03 21:08:58 incoming HTTP request from 172.18.0.4:38050
[webhook] 2017/10/03 21:08:58 tuleapPull got matched
[webhook] 2017/10/03 21:08:58 tuleapPull hook triggered successfully
[webhook] 2017/10/03 21:08:58 2017-10-03T21:08:58Z | 200 |   61.3µs | webhook.localhost | GET /hooks/tuleapPull 
[webhook] 2017/10/03 21:08:58 executing /var/webhook/scripts/tuleapPull.sh (/var/webhook/scripts/tuleapPull.sh) with arguments ["/var/webhook/scripts/tuleapPull.sh"] and environment [] using /var/repo/ as cwd
[webhook] 2017/10/03 21:08:58 command output: current directory:  + /var/repo
pulling from git
clear drupal cache
Script finished successful
testPull

[webhook] 2017/10/03 21:08:58 finished handling tuleapPull
```

So the script seems to be executed correctly, but the important commands are not. I tested it by making new pushes to my repo, which triggers the webhook-Url and then it should let the container pull from the repo, but that doesn't happen. Only when I start the script manually, the script gets executed correctly.

Has anyone some tips where the problem might be?

Comment: when you say manually do you trigger the webhook using curl or how?

Comment: With manually I mean accessing the container via a terminal and then start the script with `sh tuleapPull.sh`

Comment: Remove `-it` from your `docker exec -ti geda-drupal gedankenbruecke/vendor/drush/drush/drush st` and see if that helps. If not then then make sure you start your container also using `docker run -itd ....`

Comment: thanks that made this command run. The `git pull` command worked for whatever reason after I added `env` and `id -a` for debugging purpose in front of it. See answer from VonC below. Thank you very much

Comment: Did you make the `-it` change ? Because `env` and `id -a` are information command and my thought was that your ran `docker exec -it` from a bash script which didn't run with a tty in place and that was creating the issue

Comment: yes, I deleted the `-it` and it worked. So your hint solved the `docker exec` command and @VonC solved the `git pull` command :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Only when I start the script manually, the script gets executed correctly.

One possible cause is the difference of environment variables and user account used in both case.
Try and display them (with `env` and `id -a`) in your script to see the differences between the two execution mode (manual or through webhook)

Comment: Well, it helped in a very surprising way :D I added your proposed commands on front of my `git pull` command and it worked. I have the feeling that the script tries to interpret sometimes not correctly. Earlier I had the following at the beginning of the script: `echo "start script"` and when I run the script, I got a symbol for an unknown letter (an empty square) followed by `cript`. So it seems like there might be a problem with `echo's` ? Is there maybe an escape letter that I should use or so? But I am very thankfull that your hint got me to solve the problem even if is a bit weird :D

Answer (score 2):

From my perspective your issues seems to be of a missing TTY

```
docker exec -ti geda-drupal gedankenbruecke/vendor/drush/drush/drush st
```

You are requiring a TTY to be available for this command to work, this is not needed as such

```
docker exec -ti geda-drupal gedankenbruecke/vendor/drush/drush/drush st
```

Next issue could be not have full paths of commands. Sometimes the PATH variables are not defined in such executions and that causes the issue. So you replace the paths with complete paths it is best

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "current directory: " + $PWD
/usr/bin/git pull
echo "pulling from git"
/usr/bin/docker exec -ti geda-drupal gedankenbruecke/vendor/drush/drush/drush st
echo "clear drupal cache"
echo "Script finished successful"
echo "testPull"
```

Comment: As commented, that does solve the `docker exec` command, good point. +1

Comment: yep, thanks for your contribution. Problem is solved.